# Compile fails in snapshot view

Tags: clearcase, snapshot-view

I am trying to compile under a ClearCase snapshot view but my compile fails because all the makefiles point the root used by dynamic views.

Is there a way to go around this?

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need is to make sure your makefiles are only using path relatives to the root directory of your view, and aren't using the full path.

The other option, if you absolutely need a full path, would be to link the root directory of your snapshot or dynamic view to a specific unique (and common across all users) driver letter.